# Efficient combinations with replacement for multiple iterables, or order-independent product

Tags: python, performance, optimization, combinatorics, python-itertools

I'm trying to find a performant solution in Python that works like so:

```
>>> func([1,2,3], [1,2])
[(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,2), (2,3)]
```

This is similar to `itertools.combinations_with_replacement`, except that it can take multiple iterables. It's also similar to `itertools.product`, except that it omits order-independent duplicate results.

All of the inputs will be prefixes of the same series (i.e. they all start with the same element and follow the same pattern, but might have different lengths).

The function must be able to take any number of iterables as input.

Given a set of lists *A*, *B*, *C*, ..., here is a sketch of an algorithm that generates those results.

```
assert len(A) <= len(B) <= len(C) <= ...
for i in 0..len(A)
  for j in i..len(B)
    for k in j..len(C)
        .
        .
        .
      yield A[i], B[j], C[k], ...
```

#### Things I can't do

- Use `itertools.product` and filter the results. This has to be performant.
- Use recursion. The function overhead would make it slower than using `itertools.product` and filtering for a reasonable number of iterables.

I suspect there's a way to do this with `itertools`, but I have no idea what it is.

**EDIT:** I'm looking for the solution that takes the least time.

**EDIT 2:** There seems to be some confusion about what I'm trying to optimize. I'll illustrate with an example.

```
>>> len(list(itertools.product( *[range(8)] * 5 )))
32768
>>> len(list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(8), 5)))
792
```

The first line gives the number of **order-dependent** possibilities for rolling 5 8-sided dice. The second gives the number of **order-independent** possibilities. Regardless of how performant `itertools.product` is, it'll take **2 orders of magnitude** more iterations to get a result than `itertools.combinations_with_replacement`. I'm trying to find a way to do something similar to `itertools.combinations_with_replacement`, but with multiple iterables that minimizes the number of iterations, or time performance. (`product` runs in [image: math] whereas `combinations_with_replacement` runs in [image: math], where M is the number of sides on the die and N is the number of dice)

Comment: What kind of *"performant"*? Space? Time? You don't have to store the whole list  to filter `product`'s output, for example.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: whoops, should've stated that. I've edited the question.

Comment: what's the performance characteristics of your solution?

Comment: Can't you use `itertols.product` and then transform the result into a set of set ? Or simply make this directly with nested for?

Comment: Please explain why `itertools.product` is not "performant" and explain what kind of performance you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution hasn't recursion or filtering. It's trying to produce only ascending sequences of indices so it's usable only for prefixes of same collection. Also it's uses only indices for element identification so it's not enforces elements of series to be comparable or even hashable.

```
def prefixCombinations(coll,prefixes):
    "produces combinations of elements of the same collection prefixes"
    prefixes = sorted(prefixes) # does not impact result through it's unordered combinations
    n = len(prefixes)
    indices = [0]*n
    while True:            
        yield tuple(coll[indices[i]] for i in range(n))
        #searching backwards for non-maximum index
        for i in range(n-1,-1,-1):
            if indices[i] < prefixes[i] - 1 : break
        # if all indices hits maximum - leave
        else: break
        level = indices[i] + 1
        for i in range(i,n): indices[i] = level
```

examples are

```
>>> list(prefixCombinations([1,2,3,4,5], (3,2)))
[[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 2], [2, 3]]

>>> list(prefixCombinations([1,2,3,4,5], (3,2,5)))
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 4], [1, 1, 5], [1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 3], [1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 3], [2, 2, 4], [2, 2, 5], [2, 3, 3], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 5]]

>>> from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
>>> tuple(prefixCombinations(range(10),[10]*4)) == tuple(combinations_with_replacement(range(10),4))
True
```

Comment: I think your indentation might be off. Otherwise, this look solid.

Comment: @whereswalden indentation is ok. copypaste it and test

Comment: Whoops, I was just looking at it on my phone, which messed up the indentation for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a generator it doesn't effectively change the performance (just wraps `O(n)` around `itertools.product`):

```
import itertools

def product(*args):
    for a, b in itertools.product(*args):
        if a >= b:
            yield b, a

print list(product([1,2,3], [1,2]))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

Or even:

```
product = lambda a, b: ((y, x) for x in a for y in b if x >= y)
```

Comment: This doesn't run in O(N). It still has to iterate over every result of `itertools.product`, it just filters out some of the results. See my second edit for details.

Comment: @whereswalden: I think you misunderstood my statement, the `n` in my `O(n)` is the amount of results from `itertools.product`. It doesn't add to that. You never said that `itertools.product` has too much complexity... that changes the case indeed.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the vagueness. I hope that second edit clarified things.

Answer (score -1):

Here an implementation.
The idea is to use sorted containers to impose canonical order and avoid duplicates this way. So I'm not generating duplicates at one step and avoid need of filtering later.

It relies on "sortedcontainers" library that provides fast (as fast as C implementation) sorted containers. [I'm not affiliated to this library in any manner]

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedList as SList
#see at http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/

def order_independant_combination(*args):
    filtered = 0

    previous= set()
    current = set()

    for iterable in args:
        if not previous:
            for elem in iterable:
                current.add(tuple([elem]))

        else:
            for elem in iterable:
                for combination in previous:
                    newCombination = SList(combination)
                    newCombination.add(elem)
                    newCombination = tuple(newCombination)
                    if not newCombination in current:
                        current.add(newCombination)
                    else:
                        filtered += 1

        previous = current
        current = set()

    if filtered != 0:
        print("{0} duplicates have been filtered during geneeration process".format(filtered))
    return list(SList(previous))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = order_independant_combination(*[range(8)] * 5)
    print("Generated a result of length {0} that is {1}".format(len(result), result))
```

Execution give:

```
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3)]
```

You can test adding more iterables as parameters, it works.

Hope it can at least helps you if not solve your problem.

Vaisse Arthur.

EDIT : to answer the comment. This is not a good analysis. Filtering duplicates during generation is far most effectives than using `itertools.product` and then filters duplicates result. In fact, eliminating  duplicates result at one step avoid to generate duplicates solution in all the following steps.

Executing this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = order_independant_combination([1,2,3],[1,2],[1,2],[1,2])
    print("Generated a result of length {0} that is {1}".format(len(result), result))
```

I got the following result :

```
9 duplicates have been filtered during geneeration process
Generated a result of length 9 that is [(1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 2, 2), (1, 1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 2, 2), (1, 2, 2, 3), (2, 2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2, 3)]
```

While using itertools I got this :

```
>>> import itertools
>>> c =  list(itertools.product([1,2,3],[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]))
>>> c
[(1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 2, 1), (1, 1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 1, 1), (1, 2, 1, 2), (1, 2, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2, 2), (2, 1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 1, 2), (2, 1, 2, 1), (2, 1, 2, 2), (2, 2, 1, 1), (2, 2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2, 2), (3, 1, 1, 1), (3, 1, 1, 2), (3, 1, 2, 1), (3, 1, 2, 2), (3, 2, 1, 1), (3, 2, 1, 2), (3, 2, 2, 1), (3, 2, 2, 2)]
>>> len(c)
24
```

Simple calcul give this:

```
pruned generation : 9 result + 9 element filtered -> 18 element generated.
itertools : 24 element generated.
```

And the more element you give it, the more they are long, the more the difference will be important.

Example :

```
result = order_independant_combination([1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5])
print("Generated a result of length {0} that is {1}".format(len(result), result))
```

Result :

```
155 duplicates have been filtered during geneeration process
Generated a result of length 70 ...
```

Itertools :

```
>>> len(list(itertools.product([1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5])))
625
```

Difference of 400 elements.

EDIT 2 : with `*range(8) * 5` it gives `2674 duplicates have been filtered during geneeration process. Generated a result of length 792...`

Comment: This is actually requires the same number of iterations as using `itertools.product` then filtering. The fact that you can uncomment a line and show skipped duplicates means you're still doing filtering, it's just in-place rather than after the fact.

Comment: Edit my question to answer your comment. I think you should consider to read again the algorithm.

Comment: While your algorithm only returns non-duplicates, the time complexity is dependent on that of `itertools.product`. I need an algorithm whose time complexity is only proportional to the length of the returned sequence.